# SqlTableDependency remains some objects and slows sql response

Tags: c#, sql-server, service-broker

I use `SqlTableDependency` to monitor and receive notifications on record table change,after some days,my app slowed very much, when I open my database in SQL Server Management Studio, I see that many procedures and some other objects that created with `SqlTableDependency` are remained in database, how can I solve it?

See this:

[image]

To Dan Guzman request,i add my code bellow:

```
BackgroundWorker _bw_ProductBroker = new BackgroundWorker();
        _bw_ProductBroker.DoWork += (a, b) =>
        {
            var _ProductMapper = new TableDependency.SqlClient.Base.ModelToTableMapper<ProductM>();
            _ProductMapper.AddMappingAllProperties();
            SqlTableDependency<ProductM> _Broker;
            while (true)
                try
                {
                    b.Result = _Broker = new SqlTableDependency<ProductM>(MainVM.ConnectionString, _db.GetTableName<ProductM>(), mapper: _ProductMapper);
                    _Broker.OnChanged += ((NewAddFactorVM)b.Argument)._TblProductListener_OnChanged;
                    _Broker.OnStatusChanged += ((NewAddFactorVM)b.Argument)._TblProductListener_OnStatusChanged;
                    _Broker.Start();
                    break;
                }
                catch { Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)); continue; }
        };
        _bw_ProductBroker.RunWorkerCompleted += (a, b) =>
        {
            _TblProductListener = (SqlTableDependency<ProductM>)b.Result;
            _bw_ProductBroker?.Dispose();
        };
        _bw_ProductBroker.RunWorkerAsync(this);
```

as you see in above code,i initial SqlTableDependency object in BackgroundWorker and then pass it to my class and finally dispose the BackgroundWorker object,
some times at creating object or start it an error occurs so i put it inside a try/catch and while block,when an error occurs,i continue to loop for start again,that is all of my code !

Comment: Can't say if the problem lies with your code or `SqlTableDependency` without seeing some code. Are you the one who reported [this issue](https://github.com/christiandelbianco/monitor-table-change-with-sqltabledependency/issues/100)?

Comment: yes,i report that issue